# Access entity data in WCF Data Service's ProcessingPipeline.ProcessedRequest event handler

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to access my entity data in the generic container of WCF Data Service by overriding the default constructor and wiring the         ProcessingPipeline.ProcessedRequest event to access the retrieved data from entity and apply validation logic on it.
Referenced pseudo code is:

```
this.ProcessingPipeline.ProcessedRequest += new EventHandler<DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs>(PrecessedReq);

void PrecessedReq(object sender, DataServiceProcessingPipelineEventArgs e) 
{
 //Place I am trying to access entity data...           
}
```

Comment: I looked into this but I saw no real hook. Actually, do you want to validate outgoing data or incoming (changes, deletions etc.) ? I think that data which is already in the Db needs no validation, instead try to hook ProcessingPipeline.ProcessedChangeset and ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingChangeset

Comment: Actually I need to apply business logic while reading or updating data. So, to read and filter the records I and using ProcessedRequest hook. But to filter the records I need to access the data retreived from ORM layer and do my thibg. That is where I am stuck